I want to move the one click accesbility button on bottom of my website screen,
I want to move the one-click accessibility button on bottom of my website screen,Kindly give me a code for that

Judging by the tags you're asking about a site hosted on wordpress.com - we don't cover that here. Questions about wordpress.com should be directed to wordpress.com support, per this page: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
